# Unable to execute a procedure in loop for second time on wards in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm tried to call a method that contains execution of stored procedure in a loop but, in first tome procedure call working fine and returning result but, second time on wards it not working and even not returning any errors.

```
$list = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($dataArr); $i++)
{           

    $Test = new Test();
    $returnData = $Test->run_procedure($dataArr[$i]);

    $list[] = $returnData;
}
```

and the run procedure method code is

```
public function run_procedure($data){
    global $connection;

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, "call sp_test('$data->site', '$data->user_id', '$data->order_user_id', '$data->credit', @ledger_id1, @paid_id)");


            $procResult = mysqli_query($connection, "select @ledger_id1 as ledger_id, @paid_id paid_id;");

            $returnData = mysqli_fetch_object($procResult);
            return $returnData;
    }
```

I tried to solve this but, i didn't find any needful information. Thank you.

Comment: All of the `mysqli_*` functions return `false` on failure, so you should be checking for that and handling or throwing your own exception. What are your other `@` variables doing in your statements, are they handled elsewhere?

Comment: (@)ledger_id1, (@)paid_id are the out params of procedure not the php variables

Comment: Ah, I see. And `$credit`?

Comment: And `$connection` for that matter? You are pulling `$connection1` from global but these two other variables don't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: sorry, actually i put sample code there and i updated my question. please, check and let me know

Comment: Once again, you should perform `false` checks on your queries. `if(!$result){die(mysqli_error());}` `if(!$procResult){die(mysqli_error());}`

Answer (score 0):

Making a new connection for every time in a loop. Created a new method that returns a connection. Calling that method to create new connection and closing that connection before completion method execution.